# node.js configure file syntax error

Tags: android, json, node.js, cordova

I had installed node.js and cordova e.t.c. to develop android app but when `node create_app.js` command  is executed in CMD then it gives an error message as

```
  No config file specified.
  Searching for config.json in the current directory.
  Load Config file SyntaxError: C:\SAP\SHAT-1.0.1\WebIdeCompanion\companionapp\config.json:    
  Unexpected token S
```

Even though  `config.json` file is there in this directory  and it's content is

```
{
    "appName": "Testingapp",
    "packageName": "com.sap.ide.companion",
    "targetFolder": "CompanionApp",
    "platforms": ["android"],
    "pluginDir": "C:\SAP\MobileSDK3\KapselSDK\plugins"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried escaping the slashes inside `pluginDir`?

```
{
    "appName": "Testingapp",
    "packageName": "com.sap.ide.companion",
    "targetFolder": "CompanionApp",
    "platforms": ["android"],
    "pluginDir": "C:\\SAP\\MobileSDK3\\KapselSDK\\plugins"
}
```